# hardcoded url issue when drag & drop images with django-markdownx through S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, django-markdownx

My website works perfectly fine with [django-markdownx](https://github.com/neutronX/django-markdownx), unless I upload images.

When I drag and drop image on markdownx form, auto generated image url is added in form like below:

[image]

As you see, image is shown just fine. My storage is AWS s3, and I'm using private bucket.

The problem occurs, however, an hour later. In the markdown url query parameter `X-Amz-Expires=3600`, which is an hour. So after that the url is no longer valid, saying request has expired.

[image]

This is another expired url, but you get the idea.

I use `django-storages`, `boto3`, `AWS S3` for file storages. According to django-storages doc,

> AWS_QUERYSTRING_EXPIRE (optional; default is 3600 seconds)
>
> > The number of seconds that a generated URL is valid for.

I might extend expiry time like super long [as suggested in other post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15995212/11790764), but doesn't that mean I should update at least once every super long time period? That doesn't seem the right way.

Some suggested making S3 bucket public, but I don't want allow anyone to download my image.

I delved in [django-markdownx doc](https://neutronx.github.io/django-markdownx/) and github, without making much progress.

How can I get dynamically made presigned url when uploading image using djang-markdownx? Let me know if I'm missing anything or any suggestion is welcome.

Underneath are my django files

```
# settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "ap-northeast-2"
# AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"
# AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```